# Endorsement System Chaincode (ESCC) in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I learnt about system chaincode of Hyperledger Fabric and I know there have 5 chaincodes are: LSCC(Lifecycle system chaincode), CSCC(Configuration system chaincode), QSCC(Query system chaincode), ESCC(Endorsement system chaincode) and VSCC(Validation system chaincode). Since I want to modify some conditions in ESCC when I build a network in Hyperledger Composer then I do not know where is ESCC. Anyone please help me, your answer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

ESCC and VSCC are no longer chaincodes since Fabric v1.2, please read about [pluggable endorsement and validation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pluggable_endorsement_and_validation.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but since they said "...they can be found in the peer local configuration in the handlers section..." and i could not find it. Do you know where is the handlers section?

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L321-L370